# How can stop redirects 404 in wordpress

Tags: 404-error, nginx

Currently, all 404 errors are being redirected to the page with the following uri:

[www.example.com/woops](http://www.example.com/woops)

(previously above page was called :

[www.example.com/404-page](http://www.example.com/404-page)

however we changed the name from 404-page to woops)

Please cancel all error 404 redirects to [www.example.com/woops](http://www.example.com/woops).

Also, please cancel all error 404 redirects to [www.example.com/404-page](http://www.example.com/404-page)

We will handle 404 erros from nginx server configuiration

Comment: But nginx doesn't know whether a page exists or not. Are you asking how to get WordPress to just return the 404 code so that nginx can render the actual 404 page?

Comment: (I'm also confused by "please cancel" - we can't reconfigure your site for you.)